# Do files under /opt and /var change much other than during software installation?

Tags: software-installation, filesystem

Do files under the following mount points change other than during software installation?

- `/opt`
- `/var`

Can they be placed on read-only media?

Comment: For one, `/var` contains `/var/log` where your ever-changing log files will reside. Also `/var/run` is pretty dynamic. `/opt` will typically change with software installation only.

Answer (score 1):

Installations under `/opt`/ are always 3rd party. Updates of software installed in `/opt/` depends on the way that 3rd party believes updates need to be done. Several pieces of software I use have an "check for updates" button in their GUI. Others expect you to download a complete new version of their software and install it side by side with the old verion so they do not bother with updates of the old version. I have seen several software create log files in `/opt/` in their own log directory. It really depends on the software in question but I would say no.

`/var/`: variable files—files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system—such as logs, spool files, and temporary e-mail files.

> Can they be placed on read-only media?

- `/opt/`: No but depends on the software.
- `/var/`: no. Well, technically yes but you will need to alter all software writing to `/var/` to write elsewhere. MySQL stores it database by default in `/var/` but that can be changed. Log files tend to go to `/var/log/` but that also can be changed. Cups uses `/var/spool/` to store temp files for printing and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`/var` should not be placed on read-only media. Even the name says that much. Many volatile directories reside there - most importantly `/var/log`, as well as `/var/spool`, `/var/run`.

`/opt`, possibly, not much happens there outside of software installation.

See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html) for more information, which says this about `/var`:

> /var contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.
>
> ...
>
> /var is specified here in order to make it possible to mount /usr read-only. Everything that once went into /usr that is written to during system operation (as opposed to installation and software maintenance) must be in /var.

For `/opt`:

> Distributions may install software in /opt, but must not modify or delete software installed by the local system administrator without the assent of the local system administrator.